# Import error dll load filed не найден указанный модуль при запуске приложения на PyQt4

Tags: python, pyqt5, dll, pyqt, pyqt4

Пытаюсь установить модуль `PyQt4` на `Python 3.7` под `Windows 7 32`-разрядную версию. После создания виртуального окружения и установки `PyQt4‑4.11.4‑cp37‑cp37m‑win32.whl` `pip freeze` выдаёт следующее:

```
PyQt4==4.11.4
sip==4.19.7
```

Однако при попытке запуска приложения на Python выводится ошибка: `Import error dll load failed  не найден указанный модуль.`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите пожалйста, есть ли какой-то способ установить PyQt4 на Windows 7 32 для Python 3.5+?

Comment: Ставили из https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyqt4? Кст, посмотрите в папке питона (env) `\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4` есть ли там DLL, типа `QtGui4.dll`

Comment: Да, всё верно, ставил из этого репозитория. Эта dll-ка присутствует.

Comment: Python тоже 32-х разрядный? Нагуглил, что подобная проблема была у автора из-за разной битности питона и dll Qt

Comment: Да, Python 32-разрядный. Проверял этми способами - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1405913/how-do-i-determine-if-my-python-shell-is-executing-in-32bit-or-64bit

Comment: Ну не знаю... у меня с этим проблем не было, поэтому подсказать по существу не смогу. Можно попробовать поставить pyqt4 на чистый питон (не env), или переустановить питон, или переустановить pyqt4, или поставить pyqt5 (скорее всего придется код переписать, зато pyqt5 проще поставить: `pip install pyqt5`)

Comment: А возможно что проблема именно в ОС? Например, отсутствуют какие-то системные файлы, которые отвечают за корректную установку библиотек?

Comment: Ещё как вариант, попробовать установить от админа. Для запустить cmd.exe от администратора (через меню), активировать окружение питона и поставить

Comment: Не, это очень вряд ли. Скорее всего проблема в питоне или библиотеке (sip и pyqt4)

Comment: К сожалению запуск от имени администратора не принёс успехов для данной версии Python и библиотеки( Подскажите, стоит ли тратить время на установку разных версий Python 3.7.1-3.7.9 и пробовать совместить версию Python с этим .whl пакетом? Нужно ли проделывать эту процедуру для других версий Python (3.5, 3.6 e.t.c.) и пакетами того репозитория? Или скорее всего они все "битые"?